# What is the proper way to use ads on android?

Tags: java, android, ads

So ive been spending the last few days trying to figure out how to do ads on android running on eclipse. From what ive seen either you download a google sdk jar to use ads Googleadmobsdk jar. Or you go to previous versions, change the aar file to a zip and take out the "classes" jar and put that into your libs folder.

So my issue with using the classes jar is that i get an inflater error when the code compiles. it cannot inflate the adview in my activity_main.

The issue with using the googleadMobsdk jar is that the java code for AdRequst.Builder() does not work. it cannot find the builder part.

Problem with both is that i get an error before the code even compiles.

here is my code, currently i have the classes jar running with the code and the googleadMobsdk is not.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.coursebook.MainActivity" >
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.coursebook.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
<com.google.ads.AdView 
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-xxxxxxxxxx"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and the manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

and finally the Java code located inside onCreate()

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)       
    .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(request);
```

with this setup i get no errors until it compiles.
If i remove the classes jar and replace it with the alternative jar then again, AdRequest.Builder cannot be resolved.

here is what i am currently importing, when i switch to the other jar i need to change them, as well as the activity main back to google.

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder;
```

Comment: Warning: you're going to get a lot of people suggesting you migrate to Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

If you would have the same problem still today, you could migrate your project to Android Studio. There you can seamlessly integrate adMob into your project like this:

`Tools` > `Firebase` > `AdMob` > `Add a banner Ad to your app`